# How to remove rows in pandas with a specific condition

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am trying to remove rows from a pandas variable.

For this I created a function that analyse 2 columns in my pandas table. When this function recognise that a cell is empty, the function should remove the row.

I tried the following code :

```
def removeNaN(df):

    row,colum=df.shape

    for index in range(0,row):

        if df.Signal.iloc[index]==np.NaN or df.results.iloc[index]==np.NaN:

            df.drop(df.index[index],inplace=True)



    return df
```

The dimension of my original file is [37057 rows x 11 columns]:

```
      Unnamed: 0      created_at    ...           Signal   results
0               0  03.12.18 17:31    ...           NaN       NaN
1               1  03.12.18 17:32    ...      0.000000 -0.004039
2               2  03.12.18 17:33    ...      0.000000 -0.003910
3               3  03.12.18 17:34    ...      0.000000 -0.003297
...           ...      ...           ...         ...       ...
```

After putting the variable in my function I get exactly the same table [37057 rows x 11 columns]:

```
      Unnamed: 0      created_at    ...           Signal   results
0               0  03.12.18 17:31    ...           NaN       NaN
1               1  03.12.18 17:32    ...      0.000000 -0.004039
2               2  03.12.18 17:33    ...      0.000000 -0.003910
3               3  03.12.18 17:34    ...      0.000000 -0.003297
...           ...      ...           ...         ...       ...
```

I expect a result like this : [????? rows x 11 columns]:

```
      Unnamed: 0      created_at    ...           Signal   results
1               1  03.12.18 17:32    ...      0.000000 -0.004039
2               2  03.12.18 17:33    ...      0.000000 -0.003910
3               3  03.12.18 17:34    ...      0.000000 -0.003297
...           ...      ...           ...         ...       ...
```

Could someone help me to identify my mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easiest way to accomplish what you want would be:

```py
df.drop(df[df.Signal.isnull() | df.results.isnull()].index, inplace=True)
```

Comment: Actually, for this case I think @mfcabrera's answer is more suitable. If you wanted to check for other conditions other than isnull, then this way might be better.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly you want to remove rows when at least one of two specific columns are None/Null.

In Pandas that's easy, there's a method called dropna

`df.dropna(subset=["Signal", "results"], inplace=True)`

Subset here are the columns you want to consider.

Answer (score 0):

**Simple and easy way :**

> df.dropna(subset=['Signal','results'],axis=0)